# New badge(s) for completing maximum number of reviews (20) in a day (multiple times)

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-request

Apologies if this is a duplicate.

Currently we have the 3 following badges:

[image]

---

For 1 review, you get a bronze badge (Custodian) for each of the review types (so a maximum of 6).

For 250 reviews, you get a silver badge (Reviewer) for each of the review types (so a maximum of 6).

For 1000 reviews, you get a gold badge (Steward) for each of the review types (so a maximum of 6).

---

I propose that we have 3 new badges, in the same sort of style.

[image]

---

For completing 20 reviews in 1 day, once, you get a bronze badge (Guardian) for each of the review types (so a maximum of 6).

For completing 20 reviews in 1 day, 25 times (non consecutively), you get a silver badge (Critic) for each of the review types (so a maximum of 6).

For completing 20 reviews in 1 day, 100 times (non consecutively), you get a gold badge (Caretaker) for each of the review types (so a maximum of 6).

---

This would encourage people to not just do more reviews, but because you have the whole day to get it, you are less likely to "robo review". I would hope it wouldn't cause [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621/) sort of gaming - there is no advantage to doing them all quickly - you just have to do them over the day.

These names are just of the top off my Google search, for synonyms of the current names - I'm sure people here can think of better ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure about badges for completing the maximum number of reviews per day - especially not for 100 days.

We have enough of a problem with robo-reviewers (those who blindly accept all suggested edits etc.) just clicking whatever button gets them one step closer to the Steward badge. Having a badge for using up all your reviews on a single day will just encourage them to do this faster.

What we want is to encourage people to slow down and do *better* reviews.

Comment: My theory was that because they have the whole day, it doesn't matter if they do 20 now, or 1 every 30 mins, and take time. However, I do realise that it could encourage gaming the system, as in the linked question.

Comment: @Tim - if you have a badge for using them, it's inevitable that all people will do the reviews as quickly as possible just to get the badge.

Comment: Yeah I suppose... I guess there is no way around that? Like pace limiting? Or has that already been discussed. Instead of 20 a day, it could be 4 per hour, up to 20 a day?